# Laravel can't go to projects url when move it on live server

Tags: php, laravel, lamp

Maybe some one know the solution for my problem.

In localhost all works fine.

I bought vps server, install Ubuntu, and LAMP stack in it.

And now copy all files from localhost to live server, threw ftp.

I write ip/public in web browser and I see my projects mine path running well, but if I wanna go to url like ip/public/login it throws 404 error. (Now working only public address)

.htaccess in public folder is good.

Now I find If I write ip/public/index.php/login it works well, but I need that it work like in localhost

Comment: Does your web folder has permission `644`?

Comment: /var/www/html has 755 permission

Comment: Is .htaccess on your server enabled?

Comment: lukaskeiter how check it, I try write smth in /public/.htaccess file before RewriteEngine On, and when I go to the public address I did't get any error, is it good?

Answer (score 0):

Try making a symbolic link to your public folder and using that as the URL of your project. For example, I have a project called `inspections` in my `/var/www/html` folder. If I try to access `http://url/inspections` I get an error:

```
403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access /inspections/ on this server.
```

However, after calling this command:

```
ln -s /var/www/html/inspections/public /var/www/html/insp
```

And navigating to `http://url/insp` the page displays properly and everything works fine.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `app/storage` need to have write access (at least) in order for Laravel to work properly. I usually just do:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R app/storage
```

To activate all privileges and go from there. Hope that helps!

Comment: I try wrote  ln -s /var/www/html/public /var/www/html , but it says ln: failed to create symbolic link '/var/www/html/public': File exists

Comment: There should be a subfolder in your `var/www/html/` folder for your laravel project. So `ln -s /var/www/html/name_of_project/public /var/www/html/new_name`

Comment: But why where should be sub-folder? I use only one site in my vps? Why it cant be in www/html folder?

Comment: I've never hard a Laravel Project set up as `/var/www/html`... I don't know how that would work to be honest. I guess I assumed that you created a folder for your Laravel Project and put that in your web root `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 0):

Also did you check if mod_rewrite is enabled on this server?
Maybe Overwrite is not defined for this folder?

Try:

```
<?php in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules()); ?>
```

Or this:

```
<?php die("Enabled: ". strpos(shell_exec('/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl -l'), 'mod_rewrite') !== false); ?>
```

And check if Allowoverride is enabled in your virtual host file.
The location of the file depends on the operating system and structure.

It should look a little like this:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Comment: Try your code, so second code output was 1 so I fink mode is on

Comment: That is good. Did you setup apache and the server yourself?
Check your virtual host (the location depends on your operation system and structure) configuration if Allowoverriding is enabled. I've added the code in the answer to show you how it should look like with AllowOverride

Comment: I am trying to find but I cant find it, I use Apache 2.4.7 Ubuntu

Comment: Try this in your ssh console:
`ls /etc/apache2/sites-available/`

If you didn't create your own virtual host it should be "default" or "000-default"

Comment: where is 000-default.conf and  default-ssl.conf

Comment: I paste your code in  000-default.conf restart Apache and nothing changes